# CastError: Cast to Boolean failed for value "{ '$ne': true }" (type Object) at path "deleted" because of "CastError"

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, service

i have the CastError, while im trying to update an user, i'm using the following stack:

- Database: MongoDB, mongoose, mongoose-delete
- Backend: NodeJs, ExpressJs
- Frontend: Angular

  **model class for user:**

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const mongooseDelete = require("mongoose-delete");
    const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        email: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          unique: true,
        },
        password: {
          type: String,
          select: false,
          required: true,
          unique: true,
        },
        lastname: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        enabled: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: true,
        },
        role: {
          type: ["user", "admin", "superadmin"],
          default: "user",
        },
    
        cellphone: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
      { timestamps: true, versionKey: false }
    );
    
    UserSchema.plugin(mongooseDelete, { overrideMethods: "all" });
    module.exports = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

**this way looks the register in the BD in mongo, as the class configuration works**

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"629d23627d4b57d52273634c"},"name":"pruebaadmin","email":"admin@prueba.co","password":"$2a$10$luHE1wG9F2QFpEcbbmyO7eyEU.1pvBMFeqKOvQA3v1hL7rAGbE82a","lastname":"registro","enabled":true,"role":["admin"],"deleted":false,"createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1654465378428"}},"updatedAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1654465378428"}}}
```

**in the routes i got middleware for validate the authsession and validate the form, this two pass without error, then the problem is presented in the method updateItem in controller.**

**controller for user:**

```
const { matchedData } = require("express-validator");
const { usersModel } = require("../models");
const { handleHttpError } = require("../utils/handleError.js");

/**
 * update user by id
 * @param {*} req
 * @param {*} res
 */
const updateItem = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id, ...body } = matchedData(req);
    console.log(body);
    const data = await usersModel.findOneAndUpdate(id, body);
    res.send({ data });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    handleHttpError(res, "Register can not be updated");
  }
};

module.exports = { getItems, getItem, createItem, updateItem, deleteItem };
```

**i console log the body, got this from the request:**

```
{
  name: 'pruebaadmin',     
  email: 'admin@prueba.co',
  lastname: 'registro',    
  celphone: undefined,     
  enabled: true,
  role: [ 'admin' ]
}
```

**and the full error in the backend:**

```
CastError: Cast to Boolean failed for value "{ '$ne': true }" (type Object) at path "deleted" because of "CastError"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4716:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4815:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: `"{ '$ne': true }"`,
  kind: 'Boolean',
  value: { '$ne': true },
  path: 'deleted',
  reason: CastError: Cast to boolean failed for value "{ '$ne': true }" (type Object) at path "undefined"
      at castBoolean (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\boolean.js:28:9)
      at SchemaBoolean.cast (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\boolean.js:207:12)
      at SchemaBoolean.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1189:12)
      at SchemaBoolean.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1623:15)
      at SchemaBoolean.castForQuery (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\boolean.js:236:15)
      at SchemaBoolean.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1590:20)
      at castUpdateVal (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:544:19)
      at walkUpdatePath (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:274:22)
      at castUpdate (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:96:7)
      at model.Query._castUpdate (C:\Users\alejandroromero\Projects\rancherbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4925:10) {
    stringValue: `"{ '$ne': true }"`,
    messageFormat: undefined,
    kind: 'boolean',
    value: { '$ne': true },
    path: undefined,
    reason: undefined,
    valueType: 'Object'
  },
  valueType: 'Object'
}
```

**so, the put petition i made is like this:**
**1. i use a profile component for view and edit user data, in the method  updateRegister i call a service for user, the services works for *get* and *post* petitions but right now don't work for *put* petition.
**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  Validators,
  FormControl,
} from "@angular/forms";
import { UserService } from "../user/services/user.service";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import { UserModel } from "@models/user";
import { RegisterForm } from "@interfaces/register-form";
@Component({
  selector: "app-profile",
  templateUrl: "./profile.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./profile.component.scss"],
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = "My profile";
  formSubmitted: boolean = false;
  public id: string = "";

  public user: UserModel = {} as UserModel;
  public registerForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData();

    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      email: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      name: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(25),
        Validators.minLength(3),
        Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z ]*"),
      ]),
      lastname: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(25),
        Validators.minLength(3),
        Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z ]*"),
      ]),
      cellphone: new FormControl("", [Validators.pattern("[0-9]{10}")]),
    });
  }

  loadData() {
    this.id = this.userService.getUserIdFromCookie();

    this.userService.getUserById$(this.id).subscribe((resp) => {
      this.user = resp;

      this.registerForm.patchValue({
        email: this.user.email,
        name: this.user.name,
        lastname: this.user.lastname,
        cellphone: this.user.cellphone,
      });
    });
  }

  updateRegister(id: string): void {
    const { email, name, lastname, cellphone } = this.registerForm.value;
    console.log(this.registerForm.value);
    const updateId = id;
    // console.log("updateId: ", updateId);
    // console.log("User: ", this.user);

    this.userService
      .updateUser$(
        updateId,
        email,
        name,
        lastname,
        String(cellphone) as string,
        this.user.role as ["user", "admin", "superadmin"],
        this.user.enabled as boolean
      )
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          Swal.fire("succes", "Updated register");
          this.router.navigate(["/", "component", "profile"]);
          // console.log("session started correct: ", response);
        },
        (err) => {
          Swal.fire("Error", err.error.error, "error");
          // console.log("session  error: ", error);
        }
      );
  }

  isValid(controlName: string): boolean {
    if (this.registerForm.get(controlName)?.invalid && this.formSubmitted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**when i console log the values from the form seems ok:**
`{email: 'admin@prueba.co', name: 'pruebaadmin', lastname: 'registro', cellphone: 3017957267}`

**the service for user is like this:**

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { map, mergeMap, tap, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie-service";
import { UserModel } from "@models/user";
import { RegisterForm } from "@interfaces/register-form";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class UserService {
  private readonly URL = environment.api;
  endpoint: string = "users";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cookieService: CookieService) {}

  /**
   *
   * @returns get all users in order
   */
  getAllUsers$() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.URL}/${this.endpoint}`).pipe(
      map((resp: any) => resp.data),
      catchError((err) => {
        const { status, statusText } = err;
        // console.log(status, statusText);   // colocar función para realñizar trazabilidad de errores
        return of([]);
      })
    );
  }
  /**
   *
   * @returns get  user by id
   */
  getUserById$(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.URL}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`).pipe(
      map((resp: any) => resp.data),
      catchError((err) => {
        const { status, statusText } = err;
        // console.log(status, statusText);   // colocar función para realñizar trazabilidad de errores
        return of([]);
      })
    );
  }

  /**
   *
   * @returns get user id from cookie userId
   */
  getUserIdFromCookie(): string {
    try {
      return this.cookieService.get("userId");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return "";
    }
  }

  /**
   *
   * @returns put user
   */
  updateUser$(
    updateId: string,
    email: string,
    name: string,
    lastname: string,
    cellphone: string,
    role: ["user", "admin", "superadmin"],
    enabled: boolean
  ) {
    const body = {
      updateId,
      email,
      name,
      lastname,
      cellphone,
      role,
      enabled,
    };
    try {
      console.log(body);
      return this.http.put(`${this.URL}/${this.endpoint}/${updateId}`, body);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return of([]);
    }
  }

}
```

**in the user services again console log the data to send and seems ok**
`{cellphone: "3017957267",email: "admin@prueba.co",enabled: true,lastname: "registro",name:"pruebaadmin",role: ['admin'],updateId: "629d23627d4b57d52273634c"}`

**thats why i don't understand the issue in this call:**
-¿Why in the backend is cellphone as undefined?
-¿Why the reject of put petition if i can do it whit others class whit the same specifications?
-¿What means in the cast error, path "deleted" and path "undefined"?

**some images of the procedure in interface:**

[PUT Submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMqxz.png)

[Error result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFAvv.png)

Answer (score 0):

**the problem was in backend/controller/user**

i wasn't passing the id to update, i change the method:

```
const updateItem = async (req, res) => {
 try {
   const { updateId, ...body } = req.body;
   // console.log(body);
   const data = await usersModel.findOneAndUpdate(updateId, body);
   res.send({ data });
 } catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
   handleHttpError(res, "Register can not be updated");
 }
};
```

**so, the back way of the controller, didn't get the id to use in the method update, and the info data to update.**